# Delete a key from a MongoDB document using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose, document-database

I'm using the [Mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose) Library for accessing MongoDB with node.js

Is there a way to **remove a key from a document**?  i.e. not just set the value to null, but remove it?

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, user){
  //correctly sets the key to null... but it's still present in the document
  user.key_to_delete = null;

  // doesn't seem to have any effect
  delete user.key_to_delete;

  user.save();
});
```

Comment: I thought I had found it, but after some tests: probably not. This has some good discussion on the topic though. http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-orm/browse_thread/thread/6053e3b8d4fe9098

Comment: LOL nevermind, I guess this was your post!

Answer (score 245, accepted):

In early versions, you would have needed to drop down the node-mongodb-native driver. Each model has a collection object that contains all the methods that node-mongodb-native offers. So you can do the action in question by this:

```
User.collection.update({_id: user._id}, {$unset: {field: 1 }});
```

Since version 2.0 you can do:

```
User.update({_id: user._id}, {$unset: {field: 1 }}, callback);
```

And since version 2.4, if you have an instance of a model already you can do:

```
doc.field = undefined;
doc.save(callback);
```

Comment: This has been fixed in Mongoose 2.X, so you can leave the collection out.

Comment: What's the fix?  How does one do it.  I've read the docs I have.

Comment: Either use `User.update({ _id: id }, { $unset: { field: 1 }}, callback)` or if you have a document instance, set the path to undefined and then save it: `doc.field = undefined; doc.save()`

Comment: Just a note that if you're trying to remove an old property that's no longer defined in your schema you need to do `doc.set('field', undefined)`

Comment: what about deleting `doc.field.foo` ?

Comment: Will it work if this key is an object? I.e embedded doc, or am i need to set each property of this object to undefined individualy?

Comment: @chovy delete has no effect in v 4.0.2. I guess it makes sense that you wouldn't be allowed to remove properties from a model but seems like it should just have the same effect as setting to undefined.

Comment: @evilcelery `doc.set('field', undefined)` might not be enough since strict mode (default) does not allow to set fields which are not in the schema anymore.
`doc.set('field', undefined, { strict: false })` worked fine.

Comment: @AlexanderLink I tried `strict: false` as you posted, Keystone recorded that the update was performed but the field is still there...

Comment: @AlexanderLink where are you doing the doc.set? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderLink I've spent 2 hours looking for this. you are a hero!

Comment: none of the other comments work. it should be something like this: 
`User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { $unset: { field: 1 }}, { strict: false })`.

Answer (score 73):

You'll want to do this:

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, user){
  user.key_to_delete = undefined;
  user.save();
});
```

Comment: That will just set it to null - not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: As of version 2.4.0 setting a document key to undefined will pass the $unset to mongodb http://aaronheckmann.posterous.com/mongoose-240

Answer (score 53):

I use mongoose and using any of the above functions did me the requirement. The function compiles error free but the field would still remain.

```
user.set('key_to_delete', undefined, {strict: false} );
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: Upvoting this useful answer, too bad @alexander-link didn't make it an answer back in 2015 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486926/delete-a-key-from-a-mongodb-document-using-mongoose#comment50381329_6938733)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for me, the other solutions did not work for objects nested in arrays!

Comment: @BenSower This was my case, too. Only this solution worked well because I had to delete a field with array after finding a specific document's id

Comment: Note that the string is a path to the key. So, if the object you want to delete is nested, you must path to it.
This answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 12):

At mongo syntax to delete some key you need do following:

```
{ $unset : { field : 1} }
```

Seems at Mongoose the same.

**Edit**

Check [this](http://www.mischievous.org/2010/05/experimenting-with-nodejs-and.html) example.

Comment: Can you clarify this answer and give a code example that relates to the example code above?

Comment: sorry but i am not expereinced at mongoose. Above syntax it's mongo syntax, so i suppose that driver for any language support this. I found some example, check it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove a key from collection try this method.

```
 db.getCollection('myDatabaseTestCollectionName').update({"FieldToDelete": {$exists: true}}, {$unset:{"FieldToDelete":1}}, false, true);
```

Comment: I don't believe the question was about removing the field from all documents in the collection, which is what this does

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, user){
  // user.key_to_delete = null; X
  `user.key_to_delete = undefined;`

  delete user.key_to_delete;

  user.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a side problem like using

```
function (user)
```

instead of

```
function(err, user)
```

for the find's callback ? Just trying to help with this as I already had the case.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose document is NOT a plain javascript object and that's why you can't use delete operator.(Or `unset` from 'lodash' library).

Your options are to set doc.path = null || undefined or to use Document.toObject() method to turn mongoose doc to plain object and from there use it as usual. 
Read more in mongoose api-ref: 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Example would look something like this:

```
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    let userObject = user.toObject();
    // userObject is plain object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem with all of these answers is that they work for one field. for example let's say i want delete all fields from my Document if they were an empty string `""`.
First you should check if field is empty string put it to `$unset` :

```
function unsetEmptyFields(updateData) {
  const $unset = {};
  Object.keys(updatedData).forEach((key) => {
    if (!updatedData[key]) {
      $unset[key] = 1;
      delete updatedData[key];
    }
  });
  updatedData.$unset = $unset;

  if (isEmpty(updatedData.$unset)) { delete updatedData.$unset; }

  return updatedData;
}

function updateUserModel(data){
const updatedData = UnsetEmptyFiled(data);

    const Id = "";
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: Id },
      updatedData, { new: true },
    );
}
```

Answer (score -6):

you can use 
delete user._doc.key