# unset a sub-field of a collection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to remove a sub field from all the elements in a collection using mongoose, I created a JS script for this few weeks ago and as far as I can recall it worked back then, but now seems like is not working anymore. What I was basically doing is:

```
Collection.find({'supField.myfield': {$exists: true}})
  .then(function(dataList){
      var dataId = dataList[0]._id;
      // some other stuff here
      return Collection.update({_id: dataId}, {'$unset' : {'supField.myfield':1}})
  })
  .then(function(updated){
      console.log(updated) // dumps 0
  })
```

If requiring mongoose i set the debug flag (`require('mongoose').set('debug', true)`) it dumps no update query.

This behavior is strange and I'm afraid it's been caused by some update, but it can also be some mistake on my side.

[EDIT] Apparently is a problem connected with the fact that I'm trying to update a subfield and not a normal field. But still I got no evidence of this being a problem

Comment: Have you tried unsetting with `Collection.update({"_id": dataId}, {"$unset": {"supField.myfield": ""}})`?

Comment: Just tried, not much changes. Query syntax looks quite correct to me, I took it from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6938733/2689638)

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK, apparently that's exactly the reason!