# Find and delete a field in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

suppose we have some data in mongodb

{

```
_id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c)

  title: 'MongoDB Overview', 

  description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',

  by: 'tutorials point',

  url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',

  tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],

  likes: 100, 

  comments: 'this is a comment'
```

}

The user gives the input as "comment" and I want to remove that field from a specific document after searching the document by its id.

Comment: Depends on the mongoose version. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6938733/3006854).

Comment: Thanks  user.set(eventtype, undefined, { strict: false })