# Mongoose. Remove fields on save that are not present in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a doc saved in MongoDB like this:

```
{
  title: 'title',
  author: 'author name',
  body: 'the body',
  admin: 'admin user'
}
```

And this is the schema in Mongoose:

```
var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String
});
```

I would like that on save, the "admin" field was removed from the doc, is this possible? Can I automatize this in event **pre-save**?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you are saving the blog. Ideally it should not save admin field if it is not defined in the schema

Comment: So, You need to returned the saved doc back to client but You do not want to show the admin field, right ?

Comment: Nop, the document was previously saved in the database with other mechanism, and now the admin field is not necessary...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, the correct way of removing a field that is not present in the Schema and is present in the document is:

```
doc.set('field', undefined, { strict: false }) // strict is default true, you need to add if you are using strict mode
```

You can use it for example in your middlewares, in my case in the [*pre-save*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) middleware.

I found the answer in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486926/delete-a-key-from-a-mongodb-document-using-mongoose/6938733#comment50381329_6938733) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486926/delete-a-key-from-a-mongodb-document-using-mongoose).

I can't find an automatize mode yet.

Answer (score 0):

While the suggested answer might work (didn't test myself), there's a more versatile solution to allow multiple fields and documents with one call:

```
const fields = ["admin"];
const unset = fields.reduce(
  (acc, field) => ({
    ...acc,
    [field]: 1,
  }),
  {}
);

YourModel.collection.updateMany(query, { $unset: unset });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off strict mode in your update and it should work though:

`User.update({}, {$unset: {someField: 1}}, {multi: true, strict: false});`

original answer was taken from [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4612#issuecomment-254333419)