# how to delete a key from fetched object from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know this has been asked [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486926/delete-a-key-from-a-mongodb-document-using-mongoose) but the answer in directly modifying the database, but in this case I want to remove the password from user object so that password is not send to front-end, but `delete` is not working although `user` is an object.

```
User.find({}).then(function(users) {
    let counter = 1;
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        delete user.password;
        console.log("after delete",user) // password key/value exist

        userMap[counter] = user;
        counter++;
    });

    return userMap;
});
```

any idea !! i'm using mongoose

Comment: It should have worked. Are you sure user has a field named exactly as "password". Can you show your console.log output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the `delete` keyword on the Mongoose wrapper object. `delete` keyword will work with the native Javascript objects. For that you need to use the `lean()` function provided by Mongoose.

Try this -

```
User.find({}).lean().then
```

I just added the `lean()` function after the find query. Now your objects can be modified using the `delete` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you exclude the password from the query itself? The second parameter of find let's you include/exclude the keys from your result.

```
User.find({}, { "password": 0 }).then(function(users) {
  // The users should not contain the password key here
});
```

I think this is available from `Mongoose v4.0.0`. Similarly, you can also use the select operator after find.

```
User.find({}).select({ "name": 1 }).then(function(users) {
  // Do something 
});
```

This query will only select the name of the users.