# How to delete a row in Mongoose (MongoDB wrapper)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete a row in a document via using Mongoose, a wrapper for MongoDB

```js
// this is the document
{
  'username': 'Timmy',
  'password': 'username',
  'token': '83b234bj1n23q8w' // <= I want to delete this row in the document
}
```

and how do I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.users.update(
   { username: "Timmy" },
   { $unset: { token: "" } }
)
```

check out the MongoDB [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) documentation for more information.

To do it strictly through Mongoose, it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486926/delete-a-key-from-a-mongodb-document-using-mongoose) stackover flow post goes into some workarounds for unsetting fields directly at the Mongoose model level, although some of them look relatively hacky and are version-dependent.

Comment: Umm... I'm using mongoose for MongoDB like
```js
db.users.findOneAndUpdate({
  username: 'Timmy'
}, {
  $unset: {
    'token': 'or something'
  }, function (err, res) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: yep, the `findOneAndUpdate` is a wrapper around the MongoDB [`db.collection.findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) method. Unless I am mistaken, Mongoose should expose the underlying collection for you to make the update against

Comment: Yep it works, thanks!