# select a field then send the response without the field (omit the field the right & safe way)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // long long schema, email, phoneNum ... etc
  name: String,
  password_createTime: {
    type: Date,
    select: false
  }
})
```

And inside the first middleware in my Express app, I have the following code:

```js
const userDoc = await User.findById(THE_USER_ID).select('+password_createTime')
if (userDoc.password_createTime > someDate) return next(new Error('the password got changed, your token is expired'))
// userDoc.password_createTime = undefined  bad practice 
req.loggedInUser = userDoc
```

Now I am in the 30nth middleware in the stack, and I finally want to send the response, but when I simply write

```js
res.status(200).json({ data: req.loggedInUser })
```

It sends the response with the `password_createTime` field, which should not be visible because this field must be hidden (because of the context of `select: false` property in the schema).

I have many other routes on the API, that depend on this `req.loggedInUser` property, which is getting set by the first middleware in the stack.
The problem is that some routes on the API modify the `req.loggedInUser` to change other fields, for instance, the [PATCH /users/me] route is used to update the profile of the user such as the `name` field, then it uses the `.save()` method to save the new document. which means that I can't set `userDoc.password_createTime = undefined` because it's a  *bad practice*, it will be sent to the database as undefined, *just because I wanted to remove it from the response*.

Now. The question is: I want to remove the `password_createTime` from all the responses from anywhere in my app without having to worry about it.

How can I do that?

Is there something in mongoose like:

```js
userDoc.unselect('password_createTime')
```

where I can use it in my code of my first middleware like:

```js
const userDoc = await User.findById(THE_USER_ID).select('+password_createTime')
if (userDoc.password_createTime > someDate) return next(new Error('the password got changed, your token is expired'))
userDoc.unselect('password_createTime') //  ✅ Good practice
req.loggedInUser = userDoc
```

??

By The way, I was reading this, but I believe that most of the answers here are "bad practices":

- [Delete a key from a MongoDB document using Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486926/delete-a-key-from-a-mongodb-document-using-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [custom `toJSON` transform](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#transform):

```
userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform(doc, ret, opts) {
    delete ret.password_createTime;
    return ret;
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: say you have some situations where you *do* want `password_createTime` to be present in a response. In that case, you can use a workaround:

```
const obj = req.loggedInUser.toObject();
res.status(200).json({ data: obj })
```

That's because `toJSON` (and its transforms) is only called when you JSON-stringify a Mongoose document directly. When you use `toObject` the transforms for `toJSON` aren't applied (but you can also define transforms for `toObject` as well).

Comment: Ah! How did I miss that!

Comment: Okay, and say for example I wanted later to send a response with the `password_createTime`, the transform JSON is going to prevent that. In this case, I will have to create another schema with another model?